# How to fix HttpErrorResponse 405 not allowed?

Tags: angular, nginx, flask

I have a website running on VPS that uses Flask as a backend API server, Angular frontend, and Nginx as a reverse proxy. I have SSL installed on my Nginx. The problem is that I can connect to the Flask server using HTTP but cannot connect using HTTPS.

```
https://app.my-domain.com/api/login #<---- doesn't work
http://app.my-domain.com/api/login #<---- works properly
```

Below is the error I am getting

[image]

Below is my Nginx config

```
server 
{
    server_name app.my-domain.com;
    
    #expires    0;
    #add_header Cache-Control private;

    # flask backend server
    location /api/*
    {
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/;
    proxy_redirect  http://0.0.0.0:5000/ /;

    }

    #angular static files location after compilation using ng build --configuration production
    location /
    {
    expires -1;
        default_type application/javascript;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

        root /root/workspace/FrontEnd/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }



    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-domain.com.error.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.my-domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server 
{
    if ($host = app.my-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name app.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Below is my angular code which is responsible for making the request

```
const header=new HttpHeaders({});

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}), withcredentials: true
}; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  // create var res
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  private isLogged: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    // pass var res in return
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    console.log(AUTH_API);
    return this.http.post( './api/login', formData ); #<----------
  }
}
```

Below is my flask code,

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='static')
gunicorn_error_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
app.logger.handlers.extend(gunicorn_error_logger.handlers)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}}, supports_credentials=True)

from views import LoginPageView

app.add_url_rule('/api/login', view_func=LoginPageView.as_view('login_page', app.logger), methods=['GET','POST'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am running flask using below command

```
gunicorn --workers 4 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app --worker-class eventlet
```

How do I make sure all my requests are https and working and also disable http requests?

Comment: you should put your flask code here, I think problem on the backend.

Comment: @Jack I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually caused by trying to access static files with POST instead of GET (in this case, likely Angular files).

`location /api/*` seems to be the culprit to me. Perhaps you meant `location ~ /api/*` (enabling regex) or `location /api/` (same effect). If this location block is skipped, nginx uses the next best one, which in your case serves Angular files.

Comment: adding `location ~ /api/*` and changing `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/;` to `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;` solved my problem.